# Как выделять слово "правда" в значении "хотя", "но", однако"?

Tags: пунктуация

На "Грамоте" написано: Правда - союз со значением уступки. То же,что "хотя и, однако, но". Вопреки пунктуационным правилам союз «правда» обычно выделяется запятыми, сближаясь по значению с вводным словом. Пример: С тех пор в своем бобыльском хозяйстве Дубчик обходился топором, правда, тоже старым и заржавленным, с неудобным расшатанным топорищем. В. Быков.

В "Словаре вводных слов" Остроумовой О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. написано: "Правда" - невводное, употребляется в функции союза уступки (= хотя), если стоит на стыке частей сложного предложения или между однородными членами предложения, не обособляется: У тестя был вид заправского заговорщика, правда отчаянная решимость стоила ему волнений (Ю. Трифонов).

В справочнике по пунктуации  Розенталя:  Получил новую квартиру, правда небольшую и без особых удобств (вводное слово в начале обособленного оборота).

Так как же выделять слово "правда" в значении "хотя (и)": с обеих сторон или только слева?

Answer (score 2):

Вот обычные примеры:

Особенно выигрышно смотрятся большие керамические чаши на постаментах, правда, цена их довольно высока.

Я всегда стараюсь эти границы не переходить в своей иронии ― правда, не всегда получается.

Правительственные трассы приведены в порядок, правда, боковые подъезды к ним зачастую перекопаны.

В приведенных примерах вводное слово "правда" является структурным элементом, выражающим грамматические отношения между простыми предложениями в составе сложного, но при этом никто не лишает его значения вводности. Здесь примерно та же история, что со словом "значит".

И что интересно, никаких разных разночтений, никаких собственных решений на практике письма не наблюдается, все дружно обособляют вводное слово "правда".

Поэтому правила бывают разные, но они должны опираться на грамматику, а там ясно говорится: вводные слова могут служить средствами связи как в сложном, так и в простом предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Как Вы считаете верным, так и выделяйте. К сожалению, сейчас много таких разночтений - в связи с изменением некоторых правил. Посчитали, что Розенталь в чём-то устарел. На ГИА и ЕГЭ вышли из положения следующим образом: предоставить автору право решить,что ставить или не ставить ничего, если  есть разночтения.

Вот рекомендации по проверке экзаменов от ФИПИ:

•   В спорных случаях решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста»;

Зачастую трудно определить, является ли сочетание «на первый взгляд» вводным.

«Правда…

3. Союз со значением уступки (обычно в начале предложения или части сложного предложения). То же, что «хотя и, однако, но». Вопреки пунктуационным правилам союз «правда» обычно выделяется запятыми, сближаясь по значению с вводным словом». С тех пор в своем бобыльском хозяйстве Дубчик обходился топором, правда, тоже старым и заржавленным, с неудобным расшатанным топорищем. (В. Быков. Народные мстители) «Ну как заказчики?» – интересовался ночью Колька, и похлопывал жену по мягкому телу, и смеялся – не притворялся, действительно смех брал, правда, нервный какой-то смех. (В. Шукшин. Жена мужа в Париж провожала) Погуляли хорошо, правда устали»; «Главным образом…

В некоторых источниках, например в справочнике по пунктуации Д.Э. Розенталя, содержится рекомендация обособлять сочетание «главным образом» как вводное, служащее для выделения, оценки чего-либо, а также выступающее в знач. «самое главное». Однако примеры из художественной литературы свидетельствуют о том, что слова «главным образом», не входящие в состав присоединительного оборота, обычно не обособляются»

Answer (score 1):

**

### Ответ Граммы.ру.

**

Ваше удивление относительно различий в трактовке и пунктуационного оформления слова "правда" вполне объяснимо. Дело в том, что отнесение слова "правда" в некоторых позициях к числу союзов является новшеством, введенным справочником "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" под ред. В.В. Лопатина. Д.Э. Розенталь рассматривал союзное употребление слова "правда" как одну из функций вводного слова "правда", на этом основании оно обособлялось.

> Для многих вводных слов развитие союзной функции является вполне обычным явлением, поэтому новшество встречает сопротивление даже у тех лингвистов и специалистов по подготовке текста, которые в курсе этого нововведения (многие, надо сказать, даже не догадываются о нем).

Comment: Серж, я позволю себе высказать СОБСТВЕННОЕ  мнение по этому вопросу. Есть такая очень серьезная наука, как грамматика, ею занимаются ученые-лингвисты. Есть также структура, которая занимается практической орфографией. Назвать орфографию наукой сложно, она еще не сформировалась как точная наука, притом она практически полностью зависит от грамматики, основана на грамматике.

Comment: И вот что удивительно и занимательно: орфография пытается вносить изменения в грамматику,  но при этом ведущие ученые-грамматисты  об этом не догадываются и вообще на практическую орфографию не обращают внимания. Ситуация не из лучших: высокая наука не желает снизойти до практики и там распоряжаются люди, которые не имеют для этого достаточных знаний.

Comment: Вера, вы не согласны с мнением Лопатина? Кстати, он тоже был автором академической грамматики. Я соглашусь Розенталем, который рассматривал  союзное употребление слова "правда" как одну из функций вводного слова "правда".

Comment: Честно говоря, мне не очень нравятся многие разделы академической грамматики. Например, классификация предложений там особенная, неудобная для практического пользования, да она фактически и не применяется на практике. В то же время многие важные положения современного синтаксиса можно найти только в новых учебниках. А Розенталь и без знания нового синтаксиса  выбрал, как оказывается,  более  верное решение. Поэтому я с большим уважением отношусь к Розенталю.

Comment: Вера, а какую академическую грамматику  вы имеете в виду - 80?

Comment: Да, именно эту, там особая классификация предложений, в школьной и вузовской практике она не применяется. Конечно,  один и тот же предмет можно изучать различными способами, каждый по-своему интересен и полезен, но на практике Грамматику-80 сложно применить. По крайней мере,  найти ответа на многие интересующие меня  вопросы   мне  там не удавалось.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно писать:

"С тех пор в своем бобыльском хозяйстве Дубчик обходился топором, правда тоже старым и заржавленным, с неудобным расшатанным топорищем" (или "С тех пор в своем бобыльском хозяйстве Дубчик обходился топором, правда - тоже старым и заржавленным, с неудобным расшатанным топорищем").

"Особенно выигрышно смотрятся большие керамические чаши на постаментах, правда цена их довольно высока" (или "Особенно выигрышно смотрятся большие керамические чаши на постаментах, правда. Цена их довольно высока").

"Правительственные трассы приведены в порядок, правда боковые подъезды к ним зачастую перекопаны" (или "Правительственные трассы приведены в порядок, правда; боковые подъезды к ним зачастую перекопаны").

И дело совсем не в том, как считает писатель и вводное или союз здесь слово "правда". Дело только в логике. И вводные по правилам на стыке частей сложного предложения не отделяются в той части, к которой относятся - иначе читателю не понять, к какой именно части принадлежит вводное.