# Чем заменить "правда" как союз или вводное?

Tags: выбор-слов, пунктуация

Среди международных аэропортов разных стран, — а их я повидал немало, — монгольский самый забавный: похож на ипподром полувековой давности. Правда, изнутри выглядит солиднее.

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417274/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE

Answer (score 1):

Возможно:

1. Однако внутри выглядит солиднее.
2. Но на самом деле внутри выглядит солиднее.
3. Хотя внутри выглядит солиднее.

По-моему, вставную конструкцию, которую вы обособили тире с запятыми, лучше выделить только тире. А также, на мой взгляд, *изнутри* нужно заменить на *внутри*.

Answer (score 0):

Среди международных аэропортов разных стран — **а их я повидал немало** — монгольский самый забавный: похож на ипподром полувековой давности. Но, правда ( = впрочем), внутри выглядит солиднее.

1) "Правда" здесь не вводное слово, а союз. **Из словаря:** ПРАВДА III. в зн. вводн. сл. **Действительно, в самом деле**. (также: тем не менее, всё же, однако).  IV. в зн. союза. **Хотя**.  (Этот союз, вопреки пунктуационным правилам, обычно выделяется запятыми, но интонационные паузы при чтении отсутствуют).

Заменять слово "правда" нет особой необходимости.

2) Вставка обособляется **только тире**, если на месте разрыва не было никаких знаков.

Comment: "Впрочем" лучше звучит. "Правда" - немного разговорный вариант, мне не нравится.

Comment: Насчет того, что слово - "вводное", это модератор поправил. К нему и вопрос.@Sibylla

Answer (score 0):

"Правда" можно заменить только на НО или ОДНАКО или что-то подобное. Смысла в такой замене нет никакой. Ну если только по контексту там это надо, чтобы избавиться от повтора слова.

В первом предложении запятые перед обоими тире не нужны. Для них нет никакой мотивации. У классиков в тестах иногда встречается использование запятой и тире как единого знака там, где по современным правилам достаточно просто тире, но даже этот сильно устаревший прием не применялся к оформлению вставной конструкции **с двух сторон**.

В качестве лирического отступления. Аэропорт Улан-Батора я повидал аккурат полвека назад, в 1967 г. Что там от ипподрома - в толк не возьму. Вероятно, автор как-то ассоциирует ипподром с чем-то провинциальным, да еще сильно устаревшим. Это не так. В результате - очень странный образ рождается. Это даже не стилистическая ошибка, это просто нелепость.

Comment: Среди международных аэропортов разных стран (а их я повидал немало) монгольский самый забавный: не покрытая асфальтом территория вокруг терминала похожа на дорожку ипподрома. Впрочем, внутри выглядит солиднее.@behemothus

Comment: А, вон оно чего...  Неужели до сих пор не заасфальтировали?! Ну все равно это несколько авторское, потому что для меня и ипподром не ассоциируется  с чем-то, вашими словами говоря, несолидным. Наоборот,  за состоянием бегового поля там очень даже следят.

Comment: Вы про какой год вообще? Посмотрел в Википедии -  вполне современная  архитектура, не гигантский, конечно,  но вполне пристойный и качественный.   https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%A7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD   (Не могу прямую ссылку дать.)  Что там от ипподрома - не понимаю. Впрочем, это уже флуд, далекий от вопросов языка. Всяческих успехов!

Comment: Год 2007. Жил сутки в "околоаэропортовой" деревне, исходил всю. Смешнее уланбаторского аэропорта - только в Вамене (но тот - не международный). Критику принимаю любую: то что пишу, должно быть понятно всем, а не только автору.@behemot